# .rdlc page setting for roll on paper

Tags: c#, rdlc

Using Visual Studio 2012 I have created billing receipt as **.rdlc** report. I have set page width as **3.5in**. But the receipt height would vary according to the number of items purchased. And the user will be using roll on paper. Hence the height cannot be fixed.
Is there anyways to determine the height of the page before generating or printing the report?

Comment: stackoverflow is dead, dont ask here